# Express error handling not working in Nuxt.js serverMiddleware

Tags: express, nuxt.js

I'm building a backend in the serverMiddleware directory of my Nuxt.js (v2.15) project using Express (v4.17).

I'm currently trying to implement error handling in my API routes, specifically for input validation errors. Express has a built-in default error handler as described in [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html):

> If you pass an error to `next()` and you do not handle it in a custom error handler, it will be handled by the built-in error handler; the error will be written to the client with the stack trace. The stack trace is not included in the production environment.
>
> When an error is written, the following information is added to the response:
>
> - The `res.statusCode` is set from `err.status` (or `err.statusCode`). If this value is outside the 4xx or 5xx range, it will be set to 500.

Following this I created a custom error class:

```js
// serverMiddleware/errors.js

class HTTPError extends Error {
  constructor (status) {
    super()
    this.status = status
  }
}

export class BadRequestError extends HTTPError {
  constructor () {
    super(400)
  }
}
```

And I'm using this error in my route like this:

```js
// serverMiddleware/index.js

import express from "express"
import { BadRequestError } from "./errors.js"

const app = express()

app.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // validate req
    if (typeof req.query.foo !== "string") throw new BadRequestError()

    res.sendStatus(200)
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

export default app
```

If I provide the foo query property I get a `200 OK` as expected. However if I don't provide the foo I would expect to get a `400 Bad Request` but I get a `500 Runtime Error` instead. The stack trace points to the line where the BadRequestError is thrown.

**When running this exact same code with `app.listen(...)` instead of `export default app` in an isolated Express-only project without Nuxt.js I get the `400 Bad Request` as expected.**

To further test this I created a custom error handler function to override the default of Express and added it between the route and the export:

```js
// serverMiddleware/index.js

app.get(...)

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err)
  res.status(err.status || 500).send("Something broke!")
})

export default app
```

It doesn't even arrive at this function. I get the 500 response without any logged error or the "Something broke!" message. It's still just a stack trace pointing to the throw.

**Again, when using this exact same error handler function in an isolated Express project, I get the correct 400 response with the "Something broke!" message.**

This is clearly a problem with Nuxt.js server middleware since everything works as expected in a non-Nuxt project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in error handler sets the `res.statusCode`, but it also calls `next(error)` to propagate the error further. And if a `serverMiddleware` like yours ends with such a `next(error)`, Nuxt.js intercepts it and renders an error page (with status 500 and content-type `text/html`).

To avoid this, create your own "final error handler", for example

```js
export default function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.status) res.statusCode = err.status;
  res.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
};
```

and include that after your other middleware in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  serverMiddleware: [
    "~/serverMiddleware/index",
    "~/serverMiddleware/final_error_handler"
  ]
};
```